# Specify a URL as a dependency

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I had a URL as a resource in my `ApplcationREsources.groovy`:

```
bootstrap {
    dependsOn 'jquery'
    resource url: 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', disposition: 'head'
```

Can I do the same using Asset Pipeline?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but in the manual they are refer to `//= require ` option in the `application.js` which called as `<asset:javascript href="application.js"/>`. So, maybe this will work with the CSS too. Also, I've [read in man](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#linking) about [`@import`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/import)

Comment: yes it does the same thing take a look at the default application.css created by a grails 2.4 site... its not dependency based like resources but it all works